# Maximal Independent Set and Minimal Vertex Cover.

Tags: graph-theory

Maximal Independent Set and Minimal Vertex Cover.
I can have multiple maximal independent sets for a graph..
Now for a particular **Maximal independent set** , if I remove the vertices contained in it from total vertices in a graph...then my question is am I sure to get a **minimal vertex cover**...?
Like say if the vertices of a graph are "abcde" and say if "abc" is a **maximal independent set**  then can I say for sure that "de" is a **minimal vertex cover**...?

Plz correct me if I have done something totally wrong or is the claim given wrong...by seeing [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/4VZWfVn98ge4ssE39).

Comment: bcdfg seems not minimal to me. I think you can omit c,d and one of f or g...

Comment: @PrudiiArca I think we can omit either  f or g..but anyways that clearly suggest that maximal independent set is not a complement of minimal vertex cover..am I right..?

Comment: @PrudiiArca you can not omit any vertex. By omitting $c$ for example, you won't cover the edge $(c,e)$. Peter, please write what is a minimal vertex cover contained in $\{b,c,d,f,g\}$ but not equal to it.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker you are right. That was rubbish ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @TheHolyJoker okay I guess it's actually a minimal vertex cover...yeah I committed a mistake by assuming either f or g can be sufficient for covering all the edges...but that's not true...bcdfg is actually a minimal vertex cover...

Comment: It is very confusing!

Comment: @TheHolyJoker "bcdfg" is a minimal cover.I was wrong earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be undirected graph, and $G^c$ is complement, where $G^c=(V,V\times V \setminus E)$

$S\subseteq V(G)$ is maximal independent set in $G$ $\iff$ $S$ is maxiaml clique in $G^c$.

---

As for a vertex cover:

$S\subseteq V(G)$ is a maximal independent set in $G\iff V\setminus S$ is a set cover in $G$

Proof of $\leftarrow$ direction:

Let $A\subseteq V(G)$ be some vertex cover in $G=(V,E)$.

> Prop : $\forall u,v\in V(G)\setminus A \ \  (u,v)\notin E(G)$

proof: Otherwise $A$ won't be a vertex cover.

Comment: So if I basically remove all vertices in a maximal Independent set from total vertices then I won't always get a minimal vertex cover...am I right..??

Comment: Let's make sure we are talking about the same thing. Maximal, and maximum are not the same. I think you are talking about maximum, although you are using the word maximal

Comment: yes I want to talk about maximal independent set..now I have made some clear edit..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they will be a minimal vertex cover.

First, the fact that $S$ is an independent set (not necessary maximal) means that no edge lies within $S$, so every edge meets $V\setminus S$, meaning that $V\setminus S$ is a vertex cover.

Secondly, the fact that $S$ is a maximal independent set means that for every vertex $v\in V\setminus S$, adding $v$ to $S$ does not give an independent set. Thus there is an edge meeting $v$ and some vertex in $S$. If we removed $v$ from $V\setminus S$, this edge wouldn't be covered, so we would no longer have a vertex cover. This is true for every $v\in V\setminus S$, so $V\setminus S$ is minimal.

Comment: Yes I think in the image where I have marked "bcdfg" as "not" a minimal vertex cover..is wrong...because it's actually is a minimal vertex cover..

Comment: @PeterSmith yes, removing any vertex would leave the edge from $e$ to that vertex uncovered.

Comment: Okay thank you finally got it...